# 1 day difference in joining and relieving date

Tags: job-offer, human-resources, relieving-letter, exit-planning

I have been working at company X for the last 3 years.  I recently received an offer from Company Y, however they asked me to join 1 day earlier than my last working day at Company X.

I tried to negotiate with my current employers, and they have agreed to relieve me 4 days before and will be doing all final exit formalities but they will not change the date on my relieving letter, so it will be 1 day after the joining date. I have tried buyout option as well  but they have refused.

What are my options in this case? Is it possible i can join the company Y and then tell them the reason for 1 day difference or should I ask them to let me join but start my joining date 1 day after? I still have 1 month left.

Comment: Just to confirm, what is LWD? Leave work date?

Comment: I understood it as Last Working Day

Comment: yes it is last working day

Comment: What country is this?

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations on landing the new role!

My advice would have been to immediately speak to the HR team at Company Y and let them know that you were not able to start in your new role until the specified date.  This would have been the simplest option for you, as you would not have needed to negotiate with your current employers.

However, as you have already negotiated changing your leaving date at your current employers, your options are now limited - but all is not yet lost.

Get in touch with HR or the hiring manager at the new company (call, don't email) and ask if your start date can be pushed back by a day.  It's 1 day - it shouldn't cause a significant issue UNLESS they specifically onboard new starters on a particular day of the week - in which case they may push it back a full week.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.Yes they have certain day of the week on which they do the on boarding. Is there a chance they might revoke the offer letter ? because in that case i will be jobless unless i get another offer during notice period although i would prefer to join the Y company. Both are reputed MNCs.

Comment: I would be very surprised if they did revoke the letter simply because you want to start a day later.  How close is your start date, and also what is your location?

Comment: This has happened to me before. I had to enter with a visitor's pass for 4 days and do the on-boarding the next week. Don't panic :-) But, ***do*** let them know ASAP